# Issue with iis , sql server and web application

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, iis

I have an issue when I run the web application from Visual Studio it is work fine and it is getting the data from SQL Server but when I deploy the web application on IIS all pages without connection with database working but the page with connection doesn't.

The Error :

```
Server Error in '/EmployeeCheckInAndOut' Application.

Invalid object name 'userinfo'.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'userinfo'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 21:             SqlDataReader myReader = null;
Line 22:             SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from userinfo", myConnection);
Line 23:             myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
Line 24:             //userInfo = new ConverterHelper().ConvertToUserInfo(myReader); 
Line 25:             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Source File: C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut\ApplicationDAL\DAL.cs    Line: 23
```

Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'userinfo'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +99
   ApplicationDAL.DAL.GetUserInfo() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut\ApplicationDAL\DAL.cs:23
   ApplicationBLL.ApplicationBL.GetUserInfo() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut\ApplicationBLL\ApplicationBL.cs:15
   EmployeesCHeckInAndOut.EmployeesCHeckInAndOut.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut\EmployeesCHeckInAndOut.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to the database?

Remember these:

When you run the application in Visual Studio, it runs under your credentials. But when you run it on IIS after deploying, it runs under the account set for the application pool configured for the application and generally it will be the INETUSER.

So, if you look at this closely, you might have set up an account or access to the database for your credentials, but not the INETUSER.

Provide more info where and how you are setting the connection string.

Comment: the connection string in the code as static (not in web.config) and the application pool is ASP.NETv4.0

Comment: Wherever the connection string might be, does it have the credentials set? Or does it take the current user? You may set the credentials in the connection string and then test.